# How to find top 100 data from box plot/five number summary plot?

Tags: self-study, data-visualization

Here is the homework problem. Basically, I have no idea how to get top 100 out of 400 homes just from a box plot. Not really looking for the answer explicitly, but I want to know how to read it or guess the answer.

> The following box plot was prepared based on data collected for a 
>   sample of 400 homes in zipcode 12345 and represents the distribution
>   of the number of days that a home was on the market before being sold.
>   According to the graph, the 100 homes that were on th emarket for the
>   longest time were on the market for more than _____ days.

[image: A box plot with 5-number summary (50, 90, 110, 150, 210)]

Answer (score 2):

Look at a textbook or Wikipedia to remind yourself how a boxplot is constructed. Given that there are 400 homes overall, how many homes will lie in each region of the boxplot?